# App Store server to server notifications purpose?

Tags: app-store

App Store has so called "server-to-server" notifications. That is, when you purchase in-app feature, Apple server make HTTPS request to your server's callback method (send receipt data).

The thing is - it seems to be no user information in receipt data. For example:

```
"receipt": {
    "original_purchase_date_pst": "2019-03-11 07:35:59 America/Los_Angeles",
    "unique_identifier": "cca492f511da9fb203600195aadf00b5ad11c2f8",
    "original_transaction_id": "1000000509597835",
    "expires_date": "1552389553000",
    "transaction_id": "1000000509597835",
    "quantity": "1",
    "product_id": "com.quest.subscriptiontest.pack1",
    "bvrs": "3",
    "bid": "com.quest.SubscriptionTest",
    "unique_vendor_identifier": "8F59FA71-A8AC-474F-9967-AC06366BE376",
    "web_order_line_item_id": "1000000043169670",
    "original_purchase_date_ms": "1552314959000",
    "expires_date_formatted": "2019-03-12 11:19:13 Etc/GMT",
    "purchase_date": "2019-03-12 11:16:13 Etc/GMT",
    "is_in_intro_offer_period": "false",
    "purchase_date_ms": "1552389373000",
    "expires_date_formatted_pst": "2019-03-12 04:19:13 America/Los_Angeles",
    "is_trial_period": "false",
    "purchase_date_pst": "2019-03-12 04:16:13 America/Los_Angeles",
    "original_purchase_date": "2019-03-11 14:35:59 Etc/GMT",
    "item_id": "1454809891"
  }
```

I see here only information about purchase itself and I don't see anything about the user (who made this purchase). So what is the scenario of using such notifications without user info? Is it only for calculating financial statistics or what?

Answer (score 3):

It's expected that you store user data on your own servers. This is how I do it.

1. Send receipt from iOS app to server
2. Server stores receipt as user data
3. Server uses Apple's receipt verification to get the `original_transaction_id` and store that as user data. Probably should index this column/field.
4. Subsequent Apple server-to-server notifications will contain the `original_transaction_id` which you can use to look up the user.

I have open-sourced a server that handles iOS App Store subscriptions using server-to-server notifications and active polling at https://github.com/carpenterscode/superscribe

Feel free to use it out-of-box, or reference it to get your own solution working.

Comment: Thanks. After all we decided to avoid server to server notifications for AppStore and using only client to server notifications on demand (with all troubles it will lead to for iOS users). Unlike Google and another one billing provider, Apple made server notifications totally useless. Because there is no option to pass all needed information through server callback. Good luck to Apple to stay alive next 10 years with such approach.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you missed the real advantage of server-2-server notifications. They are meant to notify the developers for change in subscription state of a user in near real-time.

```
"notification_type": "DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS"
```

This field here identifies that the user has turned off the renewal (Cancelled).

Using this feature you can get to know about state changes which are not possible to know by the help of your app.

- Change Plan (if user upgrades/downgrades the offers from Apple Settings, this is the way to know this and act accordingly)
- Cancellations
- Re-subscriptions (if done using Apple settings UI)
- Renewal of a subscription which was in billing retry window.